# Masking in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cartography, masking, esri-production-mapping

I have question on masking.

I have vegetation group layer.

Under vegetation group layer, there are 3 layer which are V_Vegetation_Miscellaneous_A, V_Vegetation_Agriculture_A, V_Vegetation_Forest_A.

In V_Vegetation_Miscellaneous_A layer, there are two subtype which is grass and secondary forest.

In V_Vegetation_Agriculture_A layer, there are six subtype which is coconut, oil palm, rubber, sundry tree, sundry non-tree.

In V_Vegetation_Forest_A, no subtype.

This layer have representation rules.

[image]

The masking rule is :-

Symbology that have polygon outline like Grass/Coconut/Oil Palm/Rubber if meet symbology that have no polygon outline such as Secondary Forest, Wet Paddy, Sundry Tree or Sundry Non-Tree  must appear no polygon outline.

But, symbology that have outline like Grass meet symbology that have polygon outline such as, coconut, oil palm, or rubber must have polygon outline.

So, the problems are;

How to mask within layer? How to mask within subtype? How to set masking rule in this situation?